# Nested Jekyll for loop not detecting 'contains'

Tags: jekyll

I've got a nested for loop which is checking to see if a file path name matches a piece of front-matter in one of my posts. The trouble I'm having is that for whatever reason the if statement isn't working, even though I can print both `file.path` and `post.assets` right before the if statement, any idea why this isn't working?

```
{% for post in site.posts limit:3 %}
  urlsToCache.push("{{ post.url }}")
  {% for file in site.static_files %}
    {% if file.path contains '{{ post.assets }}' %}
      urlsToCache.push("{{ file.path }}")
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If printed right before I have the following which leads me to believe `{% if file.path contains '{{ post.assets }}' %}` should work, but it's not.

```
jekyll-sw
/assets/posts/jekyll-sw/montezuma_sw.jpg
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a variable inside an *if* statement avoid surrounding them with curly braces, it can be accessed directly like:

```
{% if file.path contains post.assets %}
 urlsToCache.push("{{ file.path }}")
 {% endif %}
```